# Computing the Caputo fractional derivative of a polynomial

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

In fractional calculus, the Caputo derivative of a monomial has the following form:

$$\operatorname{\mathit D}_t^\alpha\,t^\beta = \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\beta-\alpha+1)}t^{\beta-\alpha}$$

I wish to compute the [Caputo derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Caputo_fractional_derivative) of $x(1+t^2)$ with respect to $t$.

I tried the following code:

```
 β = 2;
 u[x_, t_] = x*(t^0 +t^β);
 u[x, t] /. {x -> x, t^0 -> t^α/Gamma[1 - α], 
   t^β -> 
    Gamma[β + 1]/
     Gamma[β - α + 1] t^(β - α)}
```

and obtain the following output:

[image]

But I think this code is not correct. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "not interesting"? What would make it more interesting to you? You may want to make your request more specific for people to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a somewhat general implementation of the Caputo fractional derivative with arbitrary lower limit (set to $0$ by default):

```
caputo[f_, {x_, α_, a_: 0}, opts___] /; Positive[α] && ! IntegerQ[α] :=
       Module[{n = Ceiling[α], t},
              (Convolve[UnitStep[x - a] D[f, {x, n}], x^(n - α - 1), x, t, opts] /.
               t -> x)/Gamma[n - α]]
```

(A fully general routine will include the special case of integer $\alpha$, of course; that is left as an exercise for the reader.)

This should now work for any arbitrary function; e.g.

```
caputo[x^6, {x, 4/3}]
   (2187 x^(14/3))/(154 Gamma[2/3])

caputo[Sin[x], {x, 1/2}] // FullSimplify
   (Cos[x] (-I + 2 FresnelC[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sqrt[x]]) +
    (I + 2 FresnelS[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sqrt[x]]) Sin[x])/Sqrt[2]
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I can not obtain answer for x(1+t^2). Please help me for this function.

Comment: Well, are you differintegrating with respect to $x$, or with respect to $t$?

Comment: ...and $x$ is independent of $t$, no?

Comment: Then yes, it is independent. My `caputo[]` routine should work here, and the result in your post is correct, I believe. What exactly do you believe to be wrong?

Comment: I want to this derivative: caputo[x (1 + t^2), {t, 2/3}]

Comment: answer is: x (t^(2/3)/Gamma[1/3] + (2 t^(4/3))/Gamma[7/3])

Comment: I presume you're aware of $\Gamma(k+1)=k\Gamma(k)$, yes?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers I suggest @user37694 should include all this information in the question and then clear out the comments. (+1)

Comment: I want to have input caputo[x^6, {x, [Alpha]}]. Can you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately the function does not work for nonnumeric orders. But, you already gave a formula in the OP; why not use it?

Comment: Many thanks. For formula in the OP; I got output with condition. Can you help me for output without condition?

Comment: Hmm… just tested with [`CaputoD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CaputoD.html) in v13.1, but the outputs are different from yours: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7f4ce3b3-a57c-4166-a548-177020085642

Comment: @xzczd: the Caputo derivative of `x^6` for both the old and new functions look to be the same after simplification. The one for `Sin`, however, is a head-scratcher...