# Writing a function that can perform n-times fractional Caputo derivative of order alpha to a function u(x) inductively

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[image: I wrote this code, but it fails to give the intended answer which is D^(1/2) three times of x^2.]
I wrote this code, but it fails to give the intended answer which is D^(1/2) three times of x^2.
any suggestions to correct this code or write a new one.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Please do follow this advice: Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always show your due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). Images are not a substitute for including code in your question itself. Please [edit] your question,so you can inspire somebody to volunteer their time on your problem

Comment: Here it's considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Comment: thanks man .i will take your advice

Comment: In a fresh new notebook I enter `\[Alpha]=1/2; g[x_]:=x^2; r[x_]:=Assuming[0<s<x<1, 1/Gamma[1-\[Alpha]]Integrate[D[g[s],s]/(x-s)^\[Alpha],{s,0,x}]]; b[\[Alpha]_]:=Nest[r,s,\[Alpha]]; b[3]` and it responds `Warning: contradictory assumption: 0<s<s<1 and then 1/0 encountered` Can you verify that I haven't damaged your code and that you don't get these errors when you run your code in a fresh new notebook? Or is there any chance that you have a prior assignment to something that is giving you different results?

Comment: the same code of mine except for b[a]_]:=Nest[r,s,a]

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107574)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works better:

```
g = x \[Function] x^2;
Caputo[f_, \[Alpha]_] := Block[{x},
  Function @@ {
    x, 
    1/Gamma[1 - \[Alpha]] Integrate[
      D[f[s], s]/(x - s)^\[Alpha], {s, 0, x}, 
      Assumptions -> 0 < x
      ]
     }
  ]
f = Nest[Caputo[#, 1/2] &, g, 3]
```

> `Function[x, (4 Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[π]]`

Now:

```
f[x]
```

> `(4 Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

One of the key points here is to use the `Integrate`'s option `Assumption` to submit the... assumption. A further one is that the Caputo derivative is an operator: So it needs functions as arguments and has to spit out function. The mapping `r` did not do that. Also using `Function` for the encapsulation of anonymous functions comes in quite handy here.

Comment: This code works...thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: can you modify this code so that the result appear without $ and function. like the output of Nest[Caputo[#, 1/2] &, g, 3] to be in this shape(4 Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[π]).  @Henrik Schumacher

Comment: Done.  ... ...   =)

Comment: the $ disappeared from the outputs but still the function in the outputs (like this Function[x, (4 Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]] ) so can we work on the code so that the outputs appear without function  (i.e just (4 Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[\[Pi]])). thank you so much.